# Jquery datepicker change CSS beforeshowday

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Helleu,
I want to change the CSS of some single days in my datepicker because they are not available, i also want to make them not selectable. So i have a Array with dates that are not available and call to a function on beforeshowday. If I pass it like this:

```
 return [true,"test"];
```

It is selectable and applies the class test to the day. The backround color is changed, but the border stays the color of a normal day! I also want the border in the other color and if possible also want it not to be selectable. If i return false the class is not applied!

```
function highlightDays(date) {
        var timestamp = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(),date.getDate()));
        var timestamp = timestamp/1000;
        if ($.inArray(timestamp, prijzen) != -1) {
                return [true,"test"];
        }
    return [true, ''];
}
```

CSS:

```
 td.test a { 
background: red !important; 
 }
```

Comment: can add class for true or false. Your css rules are either not specific enough or not set for correct element. Inspect element in browser console and see what rules apply and order of rules. Create a demo in jsfiddel.net that shows what is or isn't working. SHould also post your code in question

Comment: css isn't specific enough and there is no `<a>` in datepicker markup  http://jsfiddle.net/Gpm3N/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is html generated by datepicker for unselectable days with eaxtra class `bad` added in `beforeShowDay`

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled bad"><span class="ui-state-default">2</span></td>
```

You can change the css using just the datepicker classes as follows:

```css
.ui-datepicker-unselectable.ui-state-disabled span.ui-state-default{
       color:red; border-color:#ffffff
 }
```

You can also get more specific using the classes you add

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Gpm3N/

Comment: Thanks,i'm a few steps ahead, because al the return false are turned to red including the border. But also the dates that are default not available (before the current date) are also red. How to turn red only the days that are in the array?

Comment: change css rule to be more specific using your class then

Comment: maybe a (big) lack in mu knowledge, but how to do that?

Comment: try `.ui-datepicker-unselectable.CLASSYOUADD span.ui-state-default{color:red; border-color:#ffffff}`